# IntelliJ 2016.3.3 (32b) JVM Error Code -6

Tags: java, memory, intellij-idea, app-startup

I was running a script against a very large text file which crashed IntelliJ (i.e. I elected to "Shut Down" intellij when the memory overload pop-up appeared).

Now am getting the below error at startup

```
"Failed to create JVM: error code -6.
JVM Path: C\Users\[username]\[AppData]\...[IntelliJ Idea 2016.3.3]\jre\jre
If you already have a 32-bit JDK installed, define a JAVA_HOME variable in Computer > System Properties > System Settings > Env Variables"
```

My idea.exe.vmoptions is as follows

```
-server
-Xms128m
-Xmx512m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=240m
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50
-ea
-Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
-XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow
```

and have set JAVA_HOME to both 32 and 64 bit JDKs to test.

Any suggestions?

Comment: `-Xmx10240m` is too much for a 32-bit process, see [this document for the solutions](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/207241105).

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. Have updated the question now (-Xmx is set to 512m)

Comment: Check .vmoptions file in the IDE config directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was related to IntelliJ 2016.3.3 compatibility with Java 1.7.

Installing Java 1.8 allowed me to run the 64b version of IntelliJ, which in turn resolved the JVM error as well.

Answer (score 1):

Go to `C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\bin\studio.exe.vmoptions` open in notpad

**-Xmx512m** to **-Xmx256m**

**-XX:MaxPermSize=250m** to **-XX:MaxPermSize=128m**

Or change:

**-Xmx750m** to **-Xmx512m**

**-XX:MaxPermSize=350m** to **-XX:MaxPermSize=250m**

Comment: I tried these in "idea.exe.vmoptions" but no success unfortunately